# Share internet connection over all users of PC

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection, ics

I would like to share an existing L2TP connection over all users of my PC. But the option "for all users" is disabled. I've enabled an ICS service, but that didn't help. How do I share it?

[image]

(Username intentionally left blank.)

Comment: Its a permission problem.  You are not logged in as an Administrator level account.

Comment: I am logged in as an Administrator level account. Even that connection was created from the same account. Probably, you meant that I should run that application with elevated rights, but I don't know how this application is named (it seems to be a `rundll` task at all).

Comment: Since nothing is in English I can't even test running the application myself.  But the fact you can't even run UAC indicates the user account used to take the screenshot wasn't an Administrator account.  If you are on a domain that might explain the reason you cannot elevate the process.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not stupid, even that you think otherwise. I know if I'm using Administator account or not. Should I provide a screenshot?

Comment: I don't think you are an idiot. You can do what you want. Since you clearly don't want my help, my attempt to help you, ends at this point. I cannot tell you how many people think they are using an Administrator account, and they find out, they are not actually using one or because they are on a domain account and they only have local Administrator permissions. **Please translate the text in the screenshot to English for everyone else that wants to help.**

Comment: Everything one needs to know has already been translated. *But the option "for all users" is disabled.* The screen is just a plain *L2TP* connection screen. You would know that if you read the question.

Comment: I don't recongize the application that is running, I am trying to verify some behavior, I need a translation in order to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this option to be available the connection needs to be created with the "Allow other people to use this connection" option enabled.

The easiest (only?) way to fix this is to destroy the connection entry and create it again with that option selected.

Comment: That's what I did exactly. Just've been curious if that was needed.